# Ensure first character of strings is uppercase in QB64

Tags: qb64

Is there a way to make sure the first char in `FirstName` and `LastName` is uppercase only?

```
DIM FirstName AS STRING
DIM LastName AS STRING

CLS

INPUT "Enter First Name: ", FirstName
INPUT "Enter Last Name: ", LastName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string functions `LEFT$` and `UCASE$` in tandem:

```
first$ = LEFT$(FirstName, 1)
last$ = LEFT$(LastName, 1)
IF first$ <> UCASE$(first$) OR last$ <> UCASE$(last$) THEN
    PRINT "error: first letter of names must be capitalized"
    END
END IF
```

If you don't want the program to exit, you could just change it to uppercase yourself by using the `MID$` statement:

```
first$ = LEFT$(FirstName, 1)
last$ = LEFT$(LastName, 1)
MID$(FirstName, 1, 1) = UCASE$(first$)
MID$(LastName, 1, 1) = UCASE$(last$)
```

For more information on string manipulation and conversions and other information, [see the QB64 wiki](http://www.qb64.org/wiki/Keyword_Reference_-_By_usage#String_Text_Manipulation_and_Conversion:).

Comment: I dubt about the use of `ELSEIF` in the seconde piece of cide. I think the code need two `IF `. On the other hand, the code might always use the two `mid$` without `IF`... if the first char is already uppercase nothing will be changed ...

Comment: @SirJoBlack Fixed the `ELSEIF` bug.  You're absolutely correct about the `IF` statements being unnecessary.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://qbasic-slc-nepal.blogspot.com/2014/12/input-any-string-and-check-whether.html) out:

```
A$ = LEFT$(FirstName$, 1) // get first character
B = ASC(A$) //change it to ascii
IF B >= 65 AND B <= 90 THEN //is it uppercase?
CK$ = "FIRST CHARACTER IS UPPERCASE"
END IF
PRINT CK$
```

Comment: You don't need to change it to ASCII.  `IF A$ >= "A" AND A$ <= "Z"` works just fine.